# How can I show size in GB for WMI output?

Tags: powershell, format, wmi

I wrote a script for formatting disk information using WMI, with the following command and syntax:

```
Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3}
```

But I need format the output to express the size in GB. How handle the output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use expressions to format your output with [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1):

For example, you can write that:

```
$Computer = 'localhost'
$DiskInfo = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3}  `
| Select-Object @{Name="Device";Expression={($_.Name)}},
                @{Name="Size";Expression={([math]::Round($_.size/1gb))}},
                @{Name="Free";Expression={([math]::Round($_.freespace/1gb))}}
```

I select the properties and format using the math method **Round** ([Math.Round Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx)). With the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\vmsilvamolina> $DiskInfo

Device Size Free
------ ---- ----
C:      223   23
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quickly response!

Comment: FYI. These are called calculated properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the output like this:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} | 
    Select DeviceID,DriveType,VolumeName,@{N="Size";E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size / 1GB)}},@{N="FreeSpace";E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace / 1GB)}}
```